# Is SO(3)/O isomorphic to SO(3)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, rotations, symmetric-groups

Is SO(3)/O isomorphic to SO(3)? By O, I mean the octahedral rotation symmetry group. My intuition says that they are not. But I don't know how to disprove it

Comment: What makes you think they are isomorphic?

Comment: I don't think that they are, let me clarify my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think any such subgroup is normal, so the quotient isn't a group. Hence it's not a group isomorphic to $SO(3)$.

Comment: Yes $SO_3$ is definitely simple, so this question is not well posed.

Comment: Thank you! Now that you point it out, its easy to show that SO(3)/O does not have a unique inverse for each element

Comment: @rviertel The issue is that multiplication is not well defined in the quotient. The definition of a normal subgroup arises from the necessity of multiplication being well defined in the quotient; that is, we can multiply (aH)(bH)=(ab)(b^{-1}Hb)H$. We need $b^{-1}Hb=H$ so we can say that $(aH)(bH)=(ab)H$.